# Change Date Format in EXCEL

Tags: excel, excel-formula

For a stupid reason the Excel change the format of my data, and converted them to kind of date format. My problem really that I am dealing with a big amont of data so the data looks like this :

**Sep.51**  where the orginal value is    **9,51**

**Oct.57** orginal value **10,57**

**Dec.80**orginal value **12,8**

**Nov.44** orginal value  **11,44**

and even sometimes so :

**06.Oct** orginal value    **10,6**

**07.Oct**   orginal value    **10,7**

so any idea how to change them or even any formula can I apply to make the change for all the data and all colums

Comment: Which version of Excel are you using ? Is there something preventing you to select all > format > standard ?

Comment: When you say `Excel change the format of my data`, did you set a format for your cells? I'm presuming that the cell are set as 'General' format?

Comment: this happens when you import a file to excel?

Comment: @dudu721 Im using excel 2013 , I tried but the worst is 
Dec.16 it should be **12,16** but the excel changed the whole value to 01.12.2016

Comment: @Zac many colums are changed the like i mentioned in the last comment  Dec.16 it should be 12,16 but the excel changed the whole value to 01.12.2016

Answer (score 0):

If the data does not respond to format changes, it may be text data.  With text data in column **A**, in **B1** enter:

```
 =MONTH(DATEVALUE("1 " & LEFT(A1,3) & " 2000")) & "," & RIGHT(A1,2)
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: @dood if I change the format from standard to TEXT it will change the value for exaple 

**05.Sep** will become **05.09.2017**

Comment: @garys-student if I change the format from standard to TEXT it will change the value for exaple 05.Sep will become 05.09.2017

Answer (score 0):

at first sort your column A to Z, now separate data which are in shape of ((Sep.51)) to column A and then seprate data which are in shape of ((07.Oct)) to column B.
at this moment try this formula on column C1 and D1 and then scroll it down:

```
C1=MONTH(DATEVALUE("1 " & LEFT(A1,3) & " 2000")) & "," & RIGHT(A1,2)

D1=MONTH(DATEVALUE("1 " & RIGHT(B1,3) & " 2000")) & "," & LEFT(B1,2)
```